# How do you build a dynamic date field that can be used in calculations for Looker Studio?

Tags: looker-studio, calculation

I've been asked to deliver a Looker Studio report that requires dynamic dates as headers.  I only have about 2 weeks of Looker Studio experience, so I'm learning as I go.  They would like a rolling 10 months equating to Previous 6 Months, Current Month, and Next 3 Months.  I need to use the dynamic dates to calculate metrics that reference the dynamic date and calculate the metric for the given month.  Since LookML does not exist in Looker Studio, I've been tried the following as suggested by ChatGPT:

**Previous 6 Months Calculation**

```
FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y%m', DATETIME_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
```

**Current Month Calculation**

```
FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y%m', DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH))
```

**Next 3 Months Calculation**

```
FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y%m', DATETIME_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH))
```

I need to add these as column headers for a table so the metrics in each column of the table calculate for the given dynamic month but am having no luck in doing so. Any assistance that could be provided to help me implement this would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Example metric calculation for Avg. Days Late Delivery]

This works when you use MONTH(TODAY()) in place of MONTH(Current Month).  I expected that this would use the Current Month calculation to calculate this metric, but instead I get the error shown in this screenshot.  I've chased down multiple rabbit holes researching how to resolve this issue using ChatGPT, Google, and others with Looker Studio knowledge within my place of work, but have not found a solution.